# Angular/Jasmine service method was not called

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine

I am trying to do simple test when user click on button it should call method from service.
But I am still getting just that method is not called.
Component.ts

```
@Component({
    ...
    providers: [MyService]
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    constructor(public myService: myService) { }
}
```

Component.html

```
<button id="myId"
        (click)="myService.myMethodX()">
</button>
```

MyService.ts

```
    @Injectable()
    
    export class MyService {
    
        constructor() { }
        myMethodX(){
           ...
        }
}
```

And in jasmine I am testing it like this.

```
const mySpyObj = jasmine.createSpyObj('MyService', ['myMethodX']);

it('...', () => {
    // Given
    const button = ...

    // When
    button.click();
    fixture.detectChanges();

    // Then
    expect(mySpyObj.myMethodX).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

but it says that its not called what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Did you provide your `mySpyObj` in `providers` to the TestBed? ?? Moreover, since you have provider in your component, you will have to override that provider in order to get it work.

Comment: @Antoniossss thats what i forgot. I added it now but it seems not to work still.

Comment: Because you are providing it on component  level, you have to override that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to inject your mock into the test scenario, right now you are using real implmenetion. Normally you would do it via `providers` on the `TestBed#configureTestModule` but you have your service to be "component" scoped not singleton, thus you must override that as well.

Here you have working example.Pay attention to the comments and especially `overrideComponent` call. It has crucial impact as without it real implementation is beeing used instead of our mock.

```
// your service
    @Injectable()
    class FooBar {
      foo() {
        return 'bar';
      }
    }
    
//your component
    @Component({
      template: `
        <button (click)="fooBar.foo()"></button>
      `,
      providers: [FooBar] // FooBar is in scope of component, not singleton, therfore....
    })
    class FooBarComponent {
      constructor(public fooBar: FooBar) {
      }
    }
    
    describe('Foobar', async () => {
      let fooMock: SpyObj<FooBar>;
      beforeEach(async () => {
        fooMock = createSpyObj<FooBar>(['foo']);
        return TestBed.configureTestingModule({
          declarations: [FooBarComponent],
        }).overrideComponent(FooBarComponent, {
          set: { // ..... threfore we are overriding component scope provider - now our mock will be provided instead of real implementation
            providers: [
              {provide: FooBar, useValue: fooMock} // here you actually start using your mock inside component
            ]
          }
        }).compileComponents();
      });

    //passes without a problems
          it('calls foo() on click', () => {
            const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(FooBarComponent);
            fixture.detectChanges();
            fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('button')).nativeElement.click();
            expect(fooMock.foo).toHaveBeenCalled();
          });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Method called `myMethodX` from your component is not a method of the service. Inside of that method service method is called (I assume), for example `myService.calculate()`.

What you should spy on and test is that method from service. You can do something like this:

```
// Arange
spyOn(myService, 'calculate');

// Act
button.click();

// Assert
expect(myService.calculate).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Second approach would be to test if method of a component is called:

```
// Arange
spyOn(component, 'myMethodX');

// Act
button.click();

// Assert
expect(component.myMethodX).toHaveBeenCalled();
```